# PHP and MYSQL Query for sum multiple column

Tags: php, android, mysql

i want to display data from database with calculate sum and mean from each row, it's look like this :

[image]

but, for now, i only can display from year until dec column, and i've done with the basic query like this :

rainfall.php

```
    <?php
$servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rainfall";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);

 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

my rainfall table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rainfall` (
  `rf_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `estate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year_rainfall` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `jan` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `feb` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mar` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `may` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jun` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `jul` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aug` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sep` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `oct` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nov` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dec` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rf_id`)
) ;
```

What should i add into the php code to showing the calculate (sum and mean) like image above ??
Need your advice ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your SQL query with this one:

```
SELECT `Year`,
    jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, `dec`,
    jan + feb + mar + apr + may + jun + jul + aug + sep + oct + nov + `dec` AS total
FROM rainfall

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Mean',
    avg(jan), avg(feb), avg(mar), avg(apr), avg(may), avg(jun),
    avg(jul), avg(aug), avg(sep), avg(oct), avg(nov), avg(`dec`),

    avg(jan) + avg(feb) + avg(mar) + avg(apr) + avg(may) + avg(jun) +
    avg(jul) + avg(aug) + avg(sep) + avg(oct) + avg(nov) + avg(`dec`)
FROM rainfall
```

Comment: i have replaced your query into my php, but the results was : 0 results... :(

Comment: OK, `dec` is a keyword in MySQL, it must be escaped. I updated the answer.

Comment: still have the same result @Boris  :(

Comment: i was added my rainfall table structure

Comment: The problem is that all data columns are `varchar(50)`. Can you update them to some numeric type (i.e. `int`)? You really can not do `sum` on `varchar` columns.

Comment: i was edited all of the types column become int... but the result is still -->  "0 results", what is the best solution for this case ?

Comment: thankyou, i just edited the query, year is should become year_rainfall , anyway tanks very much u have saved my day...